# Google plus followers in plain text

Tags: json, google-plus

How to get google plus followers in plain text? JSON or XML
https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/get doesn't have followers field key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently there is no way to get followers (or any circle information) from Google+ through the API.

Comment: This is no longer the case, please see the https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/list method.

Comment: @paulmatthews86: That API call can return the people I'm following, not my followers.

Answer (score 3):

You can do using API key, must sure Google plus followers visibility should be public

try on fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/himstar/j4932w0s/

```
var profileid = '100520061367519307358';
var apikey = 'AIzaSyAqlZ1MJSGXMSs8q5WbfvLpZTGJeHLVc2w';
var url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/' + profileid + '?key=' + apikey;
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    url: url,
    success: function (data) {
        var googlefollowcount = data.circledByCount;
        $(".googlefollowercount").html(googlefollowcount);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually there is : http://www.emoticode.net/ruby/get-google-page-followers-count-with-google-api.html

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'json'

google_api_key = 'put your google api key here'
page_id = '105672627985088123672'

data = open("https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/#{page_id}?key=#{google_api_key}").read    
obj = JSON.parse(data)

puts obj['plusOneCount'].to_i
```

using Ruby.

Comment: Link is break :'(

Answer (score 2):

in php:

```
// get api https://code.google.com/apis/console?hl=en#access
$google_api_key = 'YOUR_API';
$page_id = 'YOUR_PAGE_ID';
$data = @file_get_contents("https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/$page_id?key=$google_api_key");   
$data = json_decode($data, true);
echo $data['plusOneCount'];
```

Comment: Sorry to bring this post back up - Have you got any insite as to whether this still works?

Comment: As far as I can tell that does not return any followers (anymore?).

Comment: Just Change `echo $data['plusOneCount'];` to `echo $data['circledByCount'];`

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve all of your circles using the [People.list](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/list) method, for example:

```
...
Plus.People.List listPeople = plus.people().list("me", "visible");
listPeople.setMaxResults(5L);

PeopleFeed peopleFeed = listPeople.execute();
List<Person> people = peopleFeed.getItems();
...
```

[Try the example in the APIs Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/plus/v1/plus.people.list?userId=me&collection=visible&orderBy=best&_h=14&)

Answer (score 0):

As of August 2018 the Google+ API endpoint `https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/userId/people/collection` [is deprecated](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/people/list).

[There is a new endpoint](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people.connections/list) for getting all the contacts: `https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/me/connections`.
There is a `metadata` key in the response, and for Google+ contacts it will look somewhat like this:

```
  "metadata": {
    "sources": [
      {
        "updateTime": "2013-01-13T19:16:50.668Z", 
        "etag": "...", 
        "type": "CONTACT", 
        "id": "..."
      }, 
      {
        "etag": "...", 
        "type": "PROFILE", 
        "id": "...", 
        "profileMetadata": {
          "userTypes": [
            "GOOGLE_USER", 
            "GPLUS_USER"
          ], 
          "objectType": "PERSON"
        }
      }
    ], 
    "objectType": "PERSON"
  }
```

Note the `"GPLUS_USER"` part.