# Get followers on google plus

Tags: php, api, google-plus

I've been looking around for a way to retrieve "plusoners" or followers for a Google Plus page in plain text, but I cant find anything.

I'm looking for a method similar to the facebook graph and twitter api.

Is this possible?

**UPDATE**

I've found this script, but it is fetching the "plus ones" for a website. Is it possible to make this script print the number of followers for a google plus page instead?

```
<?php

 $url = "http://www.tomanthony.co.uk/";

 $ch = curl_init();  
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://clients6.google.com/rpc?key=******");
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '[{"method":"pos.plusones.get","id":"p","params":{"nolog":true,"id":"' . $url . '","source":"widget","userId":"@viewer","groupId":"@self"},"jsonrpc":"2.0","key":"p","apiVersion":"v1"}]');
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type: application/json'));


 $curl_results = curl_exec ($ch);
 curl_close ($ch);

 $parsed_results = json_decode($curl_results, true);

 echo $parsed_results[0]['result']['metadata']['globalCounts']['count'];

?>
```

Comment: You can use a link provided here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8811369/google-plus-followers-in-plain-text by jenn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edited to reflect updates to the Google+ APIs**

If your app uses Google+ Sign-In or requests the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login` scope, you can get a flat list of people that a person has in their circles. This isn't exactly what you're asking about though. Your request wants to get those people that follow the target individual, that still isn't possible, but the [people.list](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/list) might accomplish your goals.

Prior to [February 26, 2013](http://googleplusplatform.blogspot.com/2013/02/google-plus-sign-in.html), the API provided no method for listing people related to a user.